# visual studio razor views not recognizing model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have 2 instances of VisualStudio 2010 open and both projects are ASP.Net MVC and I'm using Razor view engine.  In the first instance, views are recognizing @model value and I get intellisense.  The second instance does not recognize the model for the view and no intellisense.  I know i have the right namespace for the model because I can run the app and get results.  What setting am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you create the new project from the ASP.NET template or changed an old existing project (ie. a WebForms project) to use ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: the second instance is an existing ASP.Net MVC 3 project that I'm editing.  The first project is a  ASP.Net MVC 4 project

Comment: Did you "downgrade" the second one (from MVC4 to MVC3)?

Comment: no, i didn't downgrade.  The second codebase is one i received from a client that I'm modifying.  The first one (the one that does recognize model) is a fresh asp.net mvc 4 project.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an issue with MVC version and the configuration of dll's to use.

Make sure you have defined all the correct versions of the MVC dll's in the config files.

I had this same issue in Visual Studio 2013, upgraded project from MVC 3 to MVC 4, made sure every config was referencing the correct dll's versions and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I just fought through this with VS2013 today; the .csproj file had set all of the references to Private (=True) and confused itself that way. Eliminating all of the Private markers (and setting SpecificVersion = False) got Visual Studio thinking clearly again.

The references are once again showing up as Private = True, but the Razor syntax hasn't broken down again (yet).